# Getting internal server error 500 after trying to make the like functionality use Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm currently trying to make my like functionality use AJAX requests so that the page doesn't refresh whenever the user likes an image, however, I've been facing a "500, internal server error" whenever I click the div which is supposed to trigger the AJAX request.

Sadly I have no idea how to troubleshoot 500, internal server error.

This is the relevant code from the view from which the user likes an image:

```
<div class="submit-btn like" id='{{ $image->id }}'>Like</div>

<script>
    var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
    var urlLike = '{{ route('likeArtwork') }}'
</script>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
$('.like').on('click', function(event) {
    var imageId = event.target.id;

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: urlLike,
        data: {
            imageId: imageId,
            _token: token
        }
    }).done(function(response) {

    });
});
```

My post route:

```
Route::post('/artwork/like', 'LikeController@likeArtwork')->name('likeArtwork');
```

And finally my likeArtwork() function:

```
public function likeArtwork(){
    $id = $request['imageId'];
    $user = Auth::user();
    $liked = Like::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('image_id', $id)->first();

    if ($liked) {
        $liked->delete();
    } else {
        $like = new Like();
        $like->image_id = $id;
        $like->user_id = $user->id;

        $like->save();
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: `var urlLike = '{{ route('likeArtwork') }}'` looks pretty much like a broken string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function likeArtwork(Request $request){
    $id = $request->input('imageId');
    $user = Auth::user();
    $liked = Like::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('image_id', $id)->first();

    if ($liked) {
        $liked->delete();
    } else {
        $like = new Like();
        $like->image_id = $id;
        $like->user_id = $user->id;

        $like->save();
    }

    echo "success";

    //return redirect()->back(); you don't want to send another request
}
```

You may want to check the image_id exists and then use the `attach()` and `detach()` [methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships). E.g. `Image::find($id)->likes()->attach(...)`.

Comment: Dang, I forgot Request $request. How foolish of me. Thanks

Comment: If I may ask 1 more question, is having the id of the image in the like button's id the best way to pass it to JavaScript?

Comment: personally I would store in a data attribute e.g. `data-imageid={{$id}}` and then use `imageId = $(this).data('imageid');`. You may also want to consider encrypting or otherwise obscuring the ID to prevent people generating likes you don't want them to.